# Custom watch action being rejected, can't find workaround

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, custom-action, watch, built-in

My site allows a user to create a watchlist of stocks. In the site, the action is referred to as "Add to watchlist". I wanted this to create a FB open graph action called "watch" but I believe this is not possible, because watching is a built in action that can only be used on video objects. As such, I've been receiving rejections from FB along the lines of:

> Your Action failed the criteria: You are trying to submit a custom action which is not permitted. Please delete this action and submit a built-in version of this action instead.

I can't use the builtin because I need to connect it to my custom "Stock" object. I've tried renaming the action and its verb conjugations every way I can think of ("add to watchlist", "track", etc), but have been rejected at least 5 times. I've run out of ideas.

I've tried to find answers on [FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#watch), and here ([1](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10619464/create-read-action-as-custom-one) [2](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10933574/custom-watch-action) [3](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10853993/how-can-i-extend-fbs-built-in-open-graph-action-type-watch/10858333#10858333)), but have so far not found a viable solution. I think FB must not like the fact that the action is called "watch" in the site itself, and so therefore I have to use the builtin. I'd rather not redo a significant piece of my site just on the off chance it might make FB's reviewers happy, so any other ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you list the 5 verbs used so we wouldn't recommend them?

Comment: There were 5 rejections, but only really 2 verbs: Watch and Track. The other attempts were conjugation variations ("is watching" vs. "watches") or other tweaks to try and get past the reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the custom action from scratch as "Track" (deleting the original action, creating a new one, posting the shared activity as an appliction administrator, and then resubmitting with the same how-to instructions) has finally resulted in an approved custom action.